# Count with DatabaseClient

Tags: spring, database, reactive-programming

i'm getting stuck in this problem.
This is my code.

```
    public Mono<Pagination<T>> getAll(Pageable pageable) {
        return db.select()
                .from(entityClazz)
                .page(pageable)
                .fetch()
                .all()
                .map(this::convertToDTO)
                .collectList()
                .map(responses -> new Pagination<>(responses, pageable.getPageNumber(), pageable.getPageSize(),
                        total rows in db))
                ;
    }
```

This is Pagination class:

```
public final class Pagination<T> {
    @JsonProperty("total")
    private final long total;

    @JsonProperty("page")
    private final int page;

    @JsonProperty("size")
    private final int size;

    @JsonProperty("items")
    private final List<T> items;
```

I want use DatabaseClient to get total rows number in database. How i do it?

I have a solution to get total number, but it have a poor performance:

```
total = getAll().count();
```

```
    public Flux<T> getAll() {
        Flux<E> entities = getRepository().findAll();
        return convertToDTO(entities);
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to reactive specification there is no pagination at all.

However, if you want to implement it you should:

- change your query to apply `.limit()` and `.offset()`
- get total pages using `.count()` and not fetching whole data from database

See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/reactive/ReactiveCrudRepository.html#count--